# WCF server not sending data to excel on another computer

Tags: c#, excel, wcf

I have a C# application which takes data in from a sensor.

It has the code below: (unfortunately not written by me and not documented, and the old developer has long left the country).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace Client
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IDataRequest
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string query(string instr, string attr);
    }

    public class DataRequest : IDataRequest
    {
        public string query(string symbol, string attr)
        {
            //data_set is a simple dictionary in another file
            Data data = MAIN.data_set[symbol].Value;
            return data.last;//numeric value of sensor reading
        }
    }

    class WCFServer
    {
        ServiceHost host = null;
        public void open()
        {
            host = new ServiceHost(
                typeof(DataRequest),
                new Uri[]{new Uri("net.pipe://localhost")});

            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IDataRequest), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), "DataRequest");

        try
        { 
            host.Open();
        }
        catch (AddressAlreadyInUseException) { }
        }

        public void close()
        {
        try
        {
            host.Close();
        }
        catch (CommunicationObjectFaultedException) { }
        }

    }
}
```

Then in Excel, I can place in a cell:
`=RTD("data",,"sensor1","last"`

Everything works fine on the one computer.

However, when I move the application and excel file to another computer, nothing works, instead of seeing the data value streaming into excel I just see #N/A. The client application itself works on another computer, so i know the C# code is fine, just something to do with the WCF link from C# to Excel.

Is there something else involved? Registration of the WCF server or anything?

Answer (score 0):

Add the servername in RTD: RTD("data,server_name,"sensor1","last"). Documentation: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/289150

Comment: How do I register the RTD server, or add the name in RTD? I have enabled all macros and don't require add ins to be signed by Trusted Publisher

Comment: Please read the Microsoft documentation mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I clicked the link you sent. I allowed all access in excel and don't block anything at all anymore. It still does not do the job. Is there something separately I need to do to digitally sign my c# WCF server?